# Depth of view for a hypercatadioptric camera

Tags: computer-vision, cameras

I am trying to determine the depth of view for a hypercatadioptric camera (camera lens system and a hyperbolic mirror) based on [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7uTa.png).

The following illustration seems pretty clear. For an image point $p$, we are looking for a virtual point $p_u$, given the parameters of the optical system.

[image: Image from [1]]

I have troubles finding the right equations in the paper, though. There is `the distribution of a virtual point` which seems to be connected to $p_u$, but is not defined anywhere.

My goal is to replicate the diagrams they have later in the paper, like e.g. this one:
[image]

Which for a mirror (blue) gives the virtual image points of the scene (red).
I would like to calculate the depth of view, so the area at which the image blur is below a threshold.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7uTa.png) [Zhang, S., Zenou, E.: Optical approach of a hypercatadioptric system depth of
field. In: 10th International Conference on Information Sciences, Signal Processing
and their Applications](http://oatao.univ-toulouse.fr/3672/1/Zhang_3672.pdf)